# “IndexError: list index out of range” in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to establish pipeline in snakePipes and while running DNA mapping I got next IndexError error.

```
(snakePipes) ~ $ DNA-mapping -i /Volumes/HD2/snakePipes_CHIP/ChiPseq -o /Volumes/HD2/snakePipes_CHIP/ChiPseq1 --mapq 5 -j 10 --dedup hg38
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 10
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    5   Bowtie2
    5   FASTQ1
    5   FASTQ2
    

rule origFASTQ2:
    input: /Volumes/HD2/snakePipes_CHIP/ChiPseq/SRR6761499_R2.fastq.gz
    output: originalFASTQ/SRR6761499_R2.fastq.gz
    jobid: 75
    wildcards: sample=SRR6761499

RuleException in line 9 of /Users/v/miniconda3/envs/snakePipes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakePipes/shared/rules/FASTQ.snakefile:
IndexError: list index out of range
Error: snakemake returned an error code of 1, so processing is incomplete!
```

When I am looking in FASTQ.snakefile:

```
rule origFASTQ1:
      input:
          indir+"/{sample}"+reads[0]+ext
      output:
          "originalFASTQ/{sample}"+reads[0]+".fastq.gz"
      shell:
          "( [ -f {output} ] || ln -s -r {input} {output} )"

line9: rule origFASTQ2:
      input:
          indir+"/{sample}"+reads[1]+ext
      output:
          "originalFASTQ/{sample}"+reads[1]+".fastq.gz"
      shell:
          "( [ -f {output} ] || ln -s -r {input} {output} )"
```

I do not understand why I see this error. I hope somebody can point me on the source of the error.

When I use --local parameter I do not see this error, however I get another error:

```
ln: illegal option -- r

usage: ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
       ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
       link source_file target_file
    output: originalFASTQ/SRR6761495_R1.fastq.gz
    shell:
        ( [ -f originalFASTQ/SRR6761495_R1.fastq.gz ] || ln -s -r /Volumes/HD2/snakePipes_CHIP/ChiPseq/SRR6761495_R1.fastq.gz originalFASTQ/SRR6761495_R1.fastq.gz )
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

as far as I understand -r option creates symbolic links relative to link location

in `/Volumes/HD2/snakePipes_CHIP/ChiPseq` I have:

```
Bowtie2         SRR6761495_R1.fastq.gz  SRR6761495_R2.fastq.gz
command.sh      SRR6761499_R1.fastq.gz  SRR6761499_R2.fastq.gz
ChIPdict.yaml   SRR6761497_R1.fastq.gz  SRR6761497_R2.fastq.gz
deepTools_qc    SRR6761498_R1.fastq.gz  SRR6761498_R2.fastq.gz  
fetch.sh        SRR6761502_R1.fastq.gz  SRR6761502_R2.fastq.gz
filtered_bam
Sambamba
rename_files.sh
```

I am working on macOS Catalina in bash shell and ln -r is valid option (I installed coreutils)

Thanks